# Can 80hp Rotax 912s be upgraded to 100hp?

Tags: rotax-912

The more recent Rotax 912's are 100 hp engines. Can the earlier 80 hp models be upgraded to 100hp - without a complete engine swap?

Comment: I don't know, but I would say upgrading would be the same as new engine. The engine will have been designed for max design power plus some margin, let's say 25%.  So max designed = 80hp, design limit = 100hp.  See the problem? You fiddle with all the bits to produce 100HP and your design margin has gone away. Even if the margin was 50%, you halve it by uprating to 100hp. To allow for this, you'd need to change the cylinder block, and the crank, and the rods, and and and...before you know it, you've got a new engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are several kit upgrade options from third parties, e.g.:

- [120HP turbo kit](http://www.zlinaero.com/allegati/note/28/Zlin%20Turbo%20912%20120hp%20Information%20Sheet.pdf)
- [125HP kit](http://zipperbigbore.com/1622-high-power/)
- [95HP kit](http://www.masterkraft.com/912XTRA.htm)

I have no idea about the pros and cons or costs. The 125HP kit "requires machining of the crank case and heads", the others seem to be additional components.